# Jquery: Fade in multiple divs with same class one by one but only ever show a max of 2 at a time?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following Jquery code to fade in multiple divs with the same class one by one. This works fine and I want this to remain the same.

However, I end up with about 30 occurences of the div which go all the way down my page like so:

```
Div
Div
Div
Div
Div 
Div
```

What I want is for there to only ever be a max of 2 divs visible at one time. I still want the divs to fade in one by one, but only have a max of 2 on show at any time. So if a user closes the first top div for instance then the next div will fade in.

Result:

```
Div 
Div   <---- If I close, next div fades in to replace

(Div Waiting to fade in when one of the first 2 divs is closed) etc
```

Code:

```
<script>        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var animations = [];

        $('.noti_box').each(function(i) {
            animations.push(
               $(this).hide().delay(i * 1000).fadeIn(1500).promise()
            );
        });

        $.when.apply($, animations).done(function () {
            time=setInterval(function(){
            if ( $('.noti_box:visible').length === 0 ) {
                $(".advert").fadeIn("slow");
            } },200);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2efwkxn8/

Answer (score 0):

Try to fadeIn() using the selector and also .next() which selects the next div. Example:

```js
$(".fade").not(".fade:last").click(
  function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
  }
);

$(".fade:last").click(
    function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    $(".fade:first").fadeIn("slow");
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  width: 8px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  }

div:hover {
  display: block;  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fade">
  1
</div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none">
  2
</div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none">
  3
</div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none">
  4
</div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none">
  5
</div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none">
  6
</div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none">
  7
</div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none">
  8
</div>
```

Comment: oMiKeY thanks for your code however this isn't quite right, I want a new div to fade in whenever a user closes any div not just the last one at the bottom

Comment: OMiKey this is more like what I need, however I need 2 divs to show and each one fade in one by one, then when I click to close one it shows another and another and another etc but only ever showing 2 at a time